# How to "extend" factory methods when extending class with companion object with factory methods

Tags: scala, factory-pattern, companion-object

Say you have a class Foo, which is an abstraction over some kind of text file, and a companion object with factory methods that simplifies creation of Foo:

```
class Foo(val lines : Seq[String], filePath : String) { ... }

object Foo {
  def apply(file : File) : Foo = { new Foo(scala.io.Source.fromFile(file, "ISO-8859-1").mkString.split("\n").toList, file.getPath }
  def apply(file : String) : Foo = { apply(new File(file) }
}
```

What happens when you want to extend `Foo` as `Bar` and `Baz`, if both subclasses need to have the same factory methods?  You don't want to copy the companion object `Foo` as companion object `Bar` and companion object `Baz`, so what is the right way of making the factory methods "generic"?

Comment: Why not having your `object` extending a common `trait`, (dealing with generics)?

Comment: @Mik378 If I understand your suggestion correctly, the issue with that would be that the return type of factory methods wouldn't be right, no? Unless you parametrize the common trait, which gets cumbersome, I think. But maybe I didn't understand you suggestion?

Comment: I've just made a potential solution below.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
trait FooFactory[T <: Foo] {
   def apply(file : File) : T = //to be implement in your Baz and Bar class
   def apply(file : String) : T = { apply(new File(file) }   //shared method, no need to implement in subclassing classes

}


//example for Bar implementation------------------------------

class Bar extends Foo {
     // any specific Bar code here
}

object Bar extends FooFactory[Bar] {
  def apply(file : File) : Bar = { new Bar(scala.io.Source.fromFile(file, "ISO-8859-1").mkString.split("\n").toList, file.getPath }
}
```